# Close after Login

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this VB .NET code. It is for a login:

```
If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid License/Password!")
    Else
        MainForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
```

The problem is the hide. Because when I close the program with the MainForm exit windows button, don´t close.

If I put it `Me.Close()` close all the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Project properties and under **Application** tab set the **Shutdown Mode** to **When Last Form Closes** and you can use the `Me.Close()` with no problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could the `Me.Close()` to the `FormClosing` event that fires when you close `MainForm`. That way when `MainForm` closes it would trigger the `Me.Close()` as well.